# text-decoration on a tag not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, text-decorations

I am trying to remove all link styling from an `<a>` tag. I have tried all sorts of things and nothing is working. I can get the underlining to go away but visited links still remain a different color. The easy fix would be to just set the color of the text up front (and that works) but I don't want that. I reproduced the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/qod4dz5x/

I am assuming it's got something to do with me having an `<h2>` tag within the `<a>` tag?

```
<a href="http://google.com"><h2>
Google
</h2></a>


a:link {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks for any helpful input.

Comment: `text-decoration` just gets rid of the underline, not the color.

Comment: But shouldn't a:visited text-decoration:none basically deny any textdecoration?

Comment: Yes, but `text-decoration` deals with just the underlining.

Comment: blah. the fine print.... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above by Wowsk, text-decoration refers to the underline, not the color. You need a separate rule for that:

```
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;/*important is not necessary here or in any of the other psuedo selectors */
    color:black;/* or any color*/
}
```

alternatively, you can just set the color for the `<a>` tags which will override the psuedoselectors anyway:

```
a {
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Is that not what I did in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems to be working fine. 
You can set a color to the visited, being the same color as the original. I don't think there is another way to do this.

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the pseudo-selectors **:link, :active**, etc. If you just set one general `<a>` tag set of properties as in the example below, and you will be set.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

One side note about text-decoration and color:

The *text-decoration* property does not affect text color. In my experience, the best solution to consistent  color is to set your general  tag style to include **color: inherit;**.  This way, your  tags will always be whatever color their parent element is.